# How i can sum value in mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

Mysql structure and date :

```
--
-- Table structure for table `site_links`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_links` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `link_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `link_url` text NOT NULL COMMENT,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `unlocks_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_count` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=74 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `site_links`
--

INSERT INTO `site_links` (`id`, `username`, `link_title`, `link_url`, `status`, `views_count`, `unlocks_count`, `report_count`) VALUES
(56, 'john', 't1', 'http://google.com', 1, 4, 0, 0),
(57, 'john', 't2', 'http://google.com', 1, 0, 0, 0),
(58, 'james', 't3', 'http://google.com', 1, 3, 0, 0),
(59, 'dave', 't4', 'http://google.com', 1, 8, 0, 0),
(60, 'john', 't4', 'http://google.com', 1, 5, 0, 0),
```

I need to sum value of "view_count" for username "john" , so the output should be "9"

I have tried this

```
<?php
$dpl = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`views_count`) FROM site_links WHERE username='john'",true);

echo $dpl;
?>
```

But it doesn't work correctly and i got this error "Resource id #92"

How i can do that please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you're using mysqli or something

```
<?php

$dpl = $db->query("SELECT SUM(`views_count`) as `total` FROM site_links WHERE username='john'");

$row = $dpl->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['total'];

?>
```

Comment: To add just a bit of explanation: `Resource id #92` is not an error at all - it's the id of the result object. You can then call a variety of methods on the result to get the actual data.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in

Comment: @user2005646  you have to show the code of $db what kind of object it is?